# How to code for a Greatest Common Denominator function that only takes positive integers? (Python)

Tags: python, statistics

Im trying to write a function that finds the greatest common divisor of two positive integers. I've gotten the math part right, only I'm having trouble getting the function to reject negative values. I need to have the function produce an error when a non positive integer is entered.

```
def divisor(x,y):


if (y==0) :
    return x
  else:
    return divisor(y,x%y)
  if (x or y) <0:
    raise ValueError("This function only takes positive integers!")
```

I dont get an error and my function still returns the GCD of two negative integers. I'm sure my code is off as I'm very new to this

Comment: Your indenting is broken.  Please fix.

Comment: FYI, Python doesn't require you to put parentheses around the condition in `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't combine multiple variables like that in a conditional expression. You need to compare each variable separately.

Also, you need to do that check before the other `if` statement. Otherwise, the function will return before you check for negative numbers.

```
def divisor(x,y):
    if x < 0 or y < 0:
        raise ValueError("This function only takes positive integers!")
    if (y==0):
        return x
    else:
        return divisor(y,x%y)
```

When you write `(x or y) < 0`, it calculates the value of `x or y`, then compares that to `0`. `x or y` is the first truthy value of the two variables, and any non-zero value is truthy. So if `x` is not zero, then this is equivalent to `x < 0`, and if `x` is zero it's equivalent to `y < 0`. There's no automatic distribution of `<` over `or`.

Comment: That fixed the problem with the error message, thanks! Still trying to figure out how to get the same message to pop up if a non-integer is entered

Comment: `if not isinstance(x, int) or not isinstance(y, int): raise...`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
if(x < 0 or y < 0):
    raise ValueError("etc...")
```

Also what Barmar said, put the if statement first.